# How to prevent fullscreen app showing the status bar after switching back from other apps?

Tags: android, android-studio

I used Android Studio 2.2 to create a blank fullscreen app.

[image]

So upon run, it looks like this

[image]

However, when I switch to other apps and return to this app the status bar appears again!

[image]

How can I retain the app in full screen mode even after switching back from other apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this method to your source code :

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

}
```

The OnResume method will be automatically called when you switch to the App as you mentioned . So, in this method you need to set your App to Full Screen mode .

Comment: Okay, now I am selecting this answer as it is more complete

Answer (score 1):

Set full screen mode in `onResume()` and/or `onWindowFocusChanged(boolean)` when the argument is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Pleace these two functions in your FullscreenActivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
                getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
```